# Magento free shipping if item form gift category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I wish to offer free shipping if at least one item from the Gift Set category is in the cart. I currently offer free shipping if the cart value id over $25.

Is this possible without a plugin? This option is not obvious to me and my online search has yielded nothing.

I am using magento 1.7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go in: `Promotion -> Shopping Cart Price Roles -> Add New Rule` (magento backend)

there you should create rule (under "condition" tab):

on the green plus select "Product attribute combination". Inside that, in the another green plus select "Category"

and there set category which you want.

In action tab, you can set free shipping

Comment: Thanks, those instructions were easy to follow :-)